# Installing nVidia driver what to do

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

How do I install nVidia driver? I dowloaded the nwest version from official site then I wrote sudo apt-get purge nvidia* then sudo service lightdm stop and what should I do next?

Comment: In ubuntu I have never installed the nvidia drivers directly from the official site. I enable the nvidia drivers in the configuration menu of the system because it's easier. Unless you have any special need, I think that install the drivers from the nvidia site is not the best option.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the driver that you wish to install from the nVidia drivers page. You should install a Unix driver for your system's architecture from the list [here](https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). Save it on your desktop as "nvidia.run"
2. Press CTRL + ALT + 1 and log into the terminal using your user credentials.
3. Stop the current instance of lightdm:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   ```
4. Start the installation process and configure it how you like when prompted:

   ```
   cd Desktop && sudo sh nvidia.run
   ```
5. After the installation process has completed, start your instance of lightdm:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm start
   ```
6. Go back to your desktop by pressing CTRL + ALT + 7.

And you should be all set with whatever driver version you chose. I've noticed that there's issues with dual monitor resolutions for driver version 355.11 (at least on my setup), so I'd stick with 352.55 for whatever architecture your system is.

Comment: "nvidia.run" or nvidia.run

Comment: No quotes. So the file name should be: nvidia.run

Comment: cd Desktop && sudo sh nvidia.run not working, can't find file.

Comment: Then you don't have the file on your desktop. After completing step 2, use: "cd Desktop && wget <driver URL>". Don't use quotes, and replace <driver URL> with the URL to the driver you want on nVidia's website.